# How do I convert a package made in Arch Linux by using PKGBUILD and makepkg into a package that can be used by other Linux flavors such as centOS?

Tags: centos, arch-linux, package-management, compatibility

I have made a package in Arch Linux by using the PKGBUILD and makepkg method. So the file is a .pkg.tar.xz format. My goal is to be able to somehow convert this package to a format compatible with other Linux flavors (such as centOS) so I can install it on them as well. Is there a good way to do this? Or is there another method that any of you suggest?

Comment: Take a look at this Arch Wiki - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages_for_other_distributions

Comment: But, there is no way to "convert". You can install rpm tools inside arch to create rpm packages with some chroot helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear way to "convert" Arch Linux packages into CentOS packages. The best thing you can do is to follow [this ArchWiki guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages_for_other_distributions) on how to create packages to other distributions from inside Arch.

Depending on what distribution it is, the technique will change like using virtualization or chroot. If you take a look at the wiki you will see that on specific Fedora/CentOS cases, it involves installing [`rpm-org`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rpm-org/) from AUR and create a `chroot` environment to put all needed packages inside.

But, there is no way to directly convert `PKGBUILD` into `rpm`